# CFA lavaan (R) negative variance: How can I test which variance is negative

Tags: r

I'm doing a cfa with lavaan and I geht the warning: some estimated ov variances are negative.

My model contains 8 factors and 1 second order factor:

```
FEMusiK.model <-   'Unterhaltung =~ FEMusiK1 + FEMusiK2 + FEMusiK3 + FEMusiK4
                    Erholung =~ FEMusiK5 + FEMusiK6 + FEMusiK7 + FEMusiK8 + FEMusiK9 + FEMusiK10 + FEMusiK11
                    sEmpfindungen =~ FEMusiK12 + FEMusiK13 + FEMusiK14 + FEMusiK15 + FEMusiK16 + FEMusiK17 + FEMusiK18
                    Ablenkung =~ FEMusiK19 + FEMusiK20 + FEMusiK21 + FEMusiK22 + FEMusiK23
                    Entladung =~ FEMusiK24 + FEMusiK25 + FEMusiK26 + FEMusiK27 + FEMusiK28 + FEMusiK29
                    mArbeit =~ FEMusiK30 + FEMusiK31 + FEMusiK32 + FEMusiK33 + FEMusiK34
                    Trost =~ FEMusiK35 + FEMusiK36 + FEMusiK37 + FEMusiK38 + FEMusiK39 + FEMusiK40
                    Immersion =~ FEMusiK41 + FEMusiK42 + FEMusiK43 + FEMusiK44 + FEMusiK45
                  
                    FEMusiK_global =~ Unterhaltung + Erholung + sEmpfindungen + Ablenkung + Entladung + mArbeit + Trost + Immersion'

FEMusiK.model.fit <- cfa(FEMusiK.model, data=Data, estimator="MLR", missing= "FIML")
summary(FEMusiK.model.fit, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized=TRUE)
```

My sample size is 78 and I did MLR as estimator because the data is non normal distributed.

How can I test, which variance is negative and how can I fix the problem?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: What did `summary(...)` show you? Did you get a warning (meaning you have results but should be careful about interpreting them) or an error (no results)?

Comment: I did get the following warning messages:
1: In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
  lavaan WARNING:
    The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov)
    does not appear to be positive definite! The smallest eigenvalue
    (= -6.457536e-16) is smaller than zero. This may be a symptom that
    the model is not identified.
2: In lav_object_post_check(object) :
  lavaan WARNING: some estimated ov variances are negative

Comment: This probably means that you have too many factors in the model, but that is a statistics question not a programming question so you should post it to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r).